# Catching change events of child elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fairly new to AngularJS and could use some help with following problem: I have a table with lots of columns and input elements. Whenever the user changes the value of an input elements I want the row set to be 'edited'. I achieved this by adding the ng-change directive to every input element:

```html
<table>
   <tr data-ng-repeat="item in vm.Model.data">
      <td>
         <input type="text" ng-model="item.Title" ng-change="item.changed=true" />
      </td>
      .
      .
   </tr>
</table>
```

The problem with this solution is that I have lots of columns and that I have to write the ng-change directive for every 'input' element. Is there a way to catch the change event of any input element on the level of the 'tr' element?

Comment: you can do ng-repeat on columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own directive that would listen an `onchange` event bubbling (ngChange directive would not work in this case).

```
.directive('onChange', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('change input', function() {
                scope.$eval(attrs.onChange);
                scope.$digest();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and use it:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in data" on-change="item.changed=true">
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/lzIQ00l7aqXYlNCekWY8?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, that's the clean solution I was lookin for!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method on my item called IsChanged that returns true/false.  Use that to try the "edited" state.  Inside that method, use the $dirty state of each item property that you care about to determine if the rows is "changed" or not.

Something like...

```
return ($scope.item.Title.$dirty || $scope.item.FirstName.$dirty);
```